# Twilio how i find answer by human/ machine and also get the response using PHP

Tags: twilio

I have send the parameter from my front end code Angular like this,

```
var params = {"PhoneNumber": Ph};
Twilio.Device.connect(params, {"Record": true, "IfMachine": 'Continue'});
```

Now, how i get the response of call attends by machine or human status i need to get the response of the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tamil, I've written a post explaining how we recommend you go about this using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) and the example in PHP:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/tracking-call-status-how-can-you-tell-if-a-human-answers-the-phone-2.html

```
<?php
# Include Twilio PHP helper library.
require "/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php";

# Create response object.
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
$response->say("Hello, press any key to hear a top secret message.");
$gather = $response->gather(array(
    'action' => "YOUR_TWIML_BIN"
));
$response->say("You did not reveal yourself to be human. Goodbye!");

print $response;

?>
```